# is there any function to process like this? mysql on vertx java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, vert.x

As you see,

If there's a existing email, don't add user
and if there's no existing email, add user.

One API processes everything so I'm trying to separate API to two APIs, User API and Database API.

If I send queries using json like

"query" :

```
["SELECT * FROM USER WHERE email='" + email + "'", 
"INSERT INTO USER VALUES('" + email + "', '" + name + "', '" + password + "')"]
```

and Database API should handle those queries at the same time.

If there's a result from `SELECT`, do `INSERT`
If not, don't `INSERT`

Is there any solution from vertx?

Thanks in advance.

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE email='" + email + "'", rs -> {
    if(!rs.result().getResults().isEmpty()) {
        handler.handle(Future.failedFuture("email already exists"));
    } else {
        connection.execute("INSERT INTO USER VALUES('" + email + "', '" + name + "', '" + password + "')", ins -> {

            if (ins.failed()) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ins.cause());
            }

            // and close the connection
            connection.close(done -> {
                if (done.failed()) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(done.cause());
                }
            });
        });
        handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(new JsonObject().put("result", "succeed")));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I do hope you're not actually sending queries to your API, and that you're using prepared statements to prevent SQL injections.

Second, you could solve your issue without much Vert.x intervention, by adding unique key to the email column, then catching exception.

In your DB:

```
alter table USER add unique (email)
```

In your application:

```
JsonArray params  = new JsonArray().add("a@a.com").add("A").add("abcd");
conn.updateWithParams("insert into user (email, name, password) values (?, ?, ?)", params,
        (r) -> {
            if (r.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("Ok!");
            }
            else {
                if (r.cause() instanceof MySQLException) {
                    MySQLException cause = (MySQLException) r.cause();
                    // 1062 is MySQL Duplicate Key
                    if (cause.errorMessage().errorCode() == 1062) {
                        // Duplicate key, ignore
                    }
                }
            }
            // Handle connection closing
});
```